# How to test pubsub message acknowledgement in go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, google-cloud-pubsub

How to write a unit test which would verify that the message is actually being acked ?

I would like to mock the pubsub message and verify that `Ack` is called but cant't realize how.

```
func processMessage(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    log.Printf("Processing message, data: %s", msg.Data)
    msg.Ack()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using interface and mocking as follows.

```
// Create an interface that'll be implemented by *pubsub.Message
type message interface{
    Ack()
}

// Accept the interface instead of the concrete struct
func processMessage(ctx context.Context, msg message) {
    log.Printf("Processing message, data: %s", msg.Data)
    msg.Ack()
}
```

Now, in the test files, create a mocked message and confirm whether `Ack` is being called. You can use [testify/mock](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock?tab=doc) for that.

Comment: I think I can not create an interface that'll be implemented by `pubsub.Message` as I do not own it

Comment: Go has implicit interfaces. You do not need to make any changes to the library to have it implement this interface. The interface in the code example I gave will work just fine without any modifications to the library. 

From documentation: "Implicit interfaces decouple the definition of an interface from its implementation, which could then appear in any package without prearrangement."

Comment: This blog could be helpful: https://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go

Comment: I am afraid I did not get the magic! I managed to declare this interface but then, `msg.Data` is undefined as I was saying, because interfaces do not let you declare fields. What then are my options? Thanks again guys.

Comment: It will not work if you need to access the fields. But in this example, you are accessing it just for logging. You can very well just use `msg` instead of `msg.Data` and make it work. However, using implicit interfaces is the idiomatic way for unit testing external calls in Go. If you cannot avoid using `msg.Data`, you'll need to test it another way. You may even have to create an unexpected function that takes this interface and test that separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface that wraps the message and a function that wraps the receive function type.

```
// message interface to pass to our message handler
type Message interface {
    GetData() []byte
    Ack()
}

// real message for pubsub messages
type msg struct {
    m *pubsub.Message
}

// returns real message data
func (i *msg) GetData() {
    return i.m.Data
}

// acks the real pubsub message
func (i *msg) Ack() {
    i.m.Ack()
}

// test message can be passed to the handleMessage function
type testMsg struct {
    d []byte
}

// returns the test data
func (t *testMsg) GetData() []byte {
    return d
}

// does nothing so we can test our handleMessage function
func (t *testMsg) Ack() {}

func main() {
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(context.Background(), "projectID")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    sub := client.Subscription("pubsub-sub")
    sub.Receive(ctx, createHandler())
}

// creates the handler, allows us to pass our interface to the message handler
func createHandler() func(ctx context.Context, m *pubsub.Message) {
    // returns the correct function type but uses our message interface
    return func(ctx context.Context, m *pubsub.Message) {
        handleMessage(ctx, &msg{m})
    }
}

// could pass msg or testMsg here because both meet the interface Message
func handleMessage(ctx context.Context, m Message) {
    log.Println(m.GetData())
    m.Ack()
}
```